# Solr splitOnCaseChange at query time?

Tags: search, solr, lucene, split

I'm getting unexpected results in Solr and hoping someone can help. My schema.xml has splitOnCaseChange="1" for the field I'm searching on (both index & query), and the default search behavior is "OR".

I have a field with the word "Airline" indexed. When i search for "Airline" I get the match. When I search for "Airline Alias", I get the match (as expected, since it's OR). However, when I search for "AirlineAlias", I am not getting a match. I was expecting the splitOnCaseChange property to separate out the term AirlineAlias query into the 2 base words. However, if that was happening, then it should be finding the match to "Airline" (i.e. it should be the exact same query as "Airline Alias").

Is my understanding correct? If so, any ideas on why I would not be getting the correct search results?

I have copied the relevant sections from the schema.xml file below.

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<fieldType name="text_en_splitting" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="true">
    <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" 
                    ignoreCase="true" 
                    words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" 
                    enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" 
                            ignoreCase="true" 
                            words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" 
                            enablePositionIncrements="true" />
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fields>

<field name="value" type="text_en_splitting" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" omitNorms="true" />
/fields> 

<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer from Jack Krupansky on the Solr mailing list, so updating here for future searchers...

> Just set autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" on the ="text_en_splitting" field 
>   type. The current setting treated AirlineAlias as the quoted phrase "Airline 
>   Alias".